# Select commonly chosen desires collage by students after first 5 rows each group

Tags: sql, oracle

With subquery I need to select after first five rows for each group of `id_student` and must common values  of `id_desireCollage` between `id_student`.

More explain : select common collages for each student desires after his five chosen desires

| ID | id_desireCollage | id_student |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 8 | 1 |
| 7 | 9 | 1 |
| 8 | 7 | 1 |
| 9 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | 12 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 12 | 3 | 2 |
| 13 | 6 | 2 |
| 14 | 5 | 2 |
| 15 | 8 | 2 |
| 16 | 9 | 2 |
| 17 | 7 | 2 |
| 18 | 4 | 3 |
| 19 | 3 | 3 |
| 20 | 2 | 3 |
| 21 | 1 | 3 |
| 22 | 8 | 3 |
| 23 | 9 | 3 |
| 24 | 7 | 3 |
| 25 | 5 | 3 |

Something like

```
select id_desireCollage 
from
    (select * 
     from desires ds 
     where ds.id_desireCollage = desires.id_desireCollage) 
group by (id_student) 
having count(*) > 5
```

Expected result is:

| id_desireCollage |
| --- |
| 7 |
| 9 |

Comment: College with `id_desireCollage = 1` is also associated with all 3 students.  Why does it not also appear in the expected output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen because it is in id_student =1 and this less than first five rows , i need after

Comment: Note; the use of an ID column to enforce an order is a ***strictly bad idea***. ID's should only ever assert uniqueness and never imply anything else. You should have another column, such as a timestamp, or a preference rank, or something else ***explicitly dedicated to the task***. ID's can become out of order for a variety of reasons, and when it goes wrong it will be hell on earth to identify and fix. ***Don't use identifiers for sorting/ranking.***

Comment: Just in passing, I think you mean [college](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/college), not [collage](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/collage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
select id_desireCollage
from
(
  select d.*,
    row_number() over (partition by id_student order by ID) as rn
  from desires d
) T
where rn > 5
group by id_desireCollage
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

If you don't want to use the row number function (as you commented), you may try the following **- supposing there are no gaps in the ID column**:

```
select id_desireCollage
from desires d
where id >= 
  (
    select min(id)+5
    from desires t 
    where t.id_student = d.id_student
  )
group by id_desireCollage
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Tv197eZE)

As suggested by @MatBailie, if you meant by *common*, that all students have selected the id_desireCollage value then you could use the following:

```
select id_desireCollage
from desires d
where id >= 
  (
    select min(id)+5
    from desires t 
    where t.id_student = d.id_student
  )
group by id_desireCollage
having count(*)=
(
  select count(distinct id_student)
  from desires 
)
```

Comment: thanks ahemd for answering , there way in subquery ? without row_number

Comment: Maybe, if there are no gaps in the ID column, i.e. 1,2,3,4,5... not 1,4,5,6,7..

Comment: @hani128 Don't avoid sub-queries. The optimiser knows how to handle them, and some functionality can't be expressed without them. Remember; SQL gets compiled to a plan, it doesn't execute naively in the order you wrote it.

Comment: @ahmed I don't think you need the fetch first at all. But, I do think the op wants collages shared amongst all students? If so, you'd need something like `HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT student_id) FROM desires)`?

Comment: @MatBailie, thank you for your feedback, as I understood, the OP wants the most selected `id_desireCollage` after the fifth selection.

Comment: There's no mention of "most selected" it only refers to "common"; `More explain : select common collages for each student desires after his five chosen desires`